# Can a GHCI config file use CPP macros?

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor, ghci

I was thinking it would be nice to set up my global GHCI config such that my commonly-used imports occur automatically when the packages that provide them are present.

I tried adding this to `~/.ghc/ghci.conf`:

```
:set -XCPP

#ifdef MIN_VERSION_containers
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import           Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
#endif
```

But apparently that does not work.

```
> stack repl
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

<interactive>:24:1: error: parse error on input ‘#’

<interactive>:29:1: error: parse error on input ‘#’
```

Is there a way to get CPP macros to work, or some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I guess that that .ghci works as if you wrote `#ifdef ...` at the GHCi prompt, failing to do anything.

Answer (score 5):

Those macros cannot be used directly by GHCI, but they *can* be used in a file you include using [GHCI's `:add` command](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:add).

For example, this is what my setup now looks like:

- `~/.ghc/ghci.conf` contains the `:add` command:

  ```
  > grep imports ~/.ghc/ghci.conf
  :add /home/chris/.ghc/imports.hs
  ```
- `~/.ghc/imports/imports.hs` contains my CPP'ed imports:

  ```
  > cat ~/.ghc/imports/imports.hs
  {-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

  #ifdef MIN_VERSION_containers
  import           Data.Set (Set)
  import qualified Data.Set as Set
  import           Data.Map (Map)
  import qualified Data.Map as Map
  #endif
  ```

Comment: Thanks to [Tim Humphries](https://twitter.com/thumphriees/status/832752388888883201) for this solution.